# Java encoding corrupted when run on a linux service?

Tags: java, linux, encoding, centos

I am running a java server with CentOS 6.3.

My problem is that Korean(EUC-KR,UTF-8) encoding is not right when jar file is run on a service. There is no problem when I simple run "java -jar example.jar".

If I run the similar command on a service, the printed text(only Korean, english works fine) becomes all "???".

Here is what my service script looks like.

```
start(){
    nohup java -jar example.jar > /root/nohup.txt 2>&1&
}
restartDevelop(){
    killall -9 java
    java -jar example.jar
}
```

Even texts printed on nohup is corrupted when run on service.("nohup java -jar example.jar" works fine)

I've tried setting "-Dfile.encoding=EUC-KR", set "new String(message.getBytes("EUC-KR"), "EUC-KR")". Nothing seems to work(tested with UTF-8 also...). I've checked il8n file and locale, and it is set correctly as ko_KR.eucKR.

Is there any setting I could change to get this right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your interactive environment - compare with the one seen by the service.

Answer (score 5):

@ Alien Life Form

You totally pointed me in the direction of my solution.

My web service programmed within the Restlet framework messed up the character encoding (UTF-8) when started as a linux service but was fine when restarted by hand or run on the command line.

Looked at Apache2 documentation (used as reverse proxy) and tried to change booting order but nothing worked.

Now I added

export LANG=en_US.UTF-8

to my start-up script

and everything works like a charm. Catalan, Spanish, German, French, all OK now on server boot!!

Thanx
Marc